# How can i use ramda.js with this code?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am beginning to use ramda, but have doubts about how to implement functions ramda.

This code is to mount a select object to do queries for sequelize.

See code:

```
const stringRequired = string => !!string.length
const numberRequired = number => Number.isInteger(number)

const validadeInput = (value, initial, validade) => (
  validade(value) ? value : initial
)

const input = (obj, key, initial, validade) => (
  typeof obj[key] !== 'undefined' ?
  validadeInput(obj[key], initial, validade) :
  initial
);

const addValue = (obj, key, value) => {
  const prop = {}
  prop[key] = value
  return Object.assign(obj, prop)
}

const addFilter = (obj, key, value, validate) => (
  validate(value) ? addValue(obj, key, value)
  : obj
)

const selector = (query = {}) => {
  const limit = input(query, 'limit', 10, numberRequired);
  const name = input(query, 'name', '', stringRequired);

  let select = {}

  select = addFilter(select, 'name', name, stringRequired);
  select = addFilter(select, 'limit', limit, numberRequired);

  return select
}

console.log(selector()); 
// { limit: 10 }
console.log(selector({ name: 'David Costa' })); 
// { limit: 10, name: 'David Costa' }
console.log(selector({ limit: 50 }));
// { limit: 50 }
```

Or see demo on link

http://jsbin.com/zerahay/edit?js,console,output

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How can i use ramda.js with this code?

Comment: @DavidCosta you dumped a bunch of (incomplete) code on the screen. Looks ok at first glance. What is the **specific** problem you are trying to solve here? What about your code isn't working the way you want it to?

Comment: My code is not incomplete, the goals is create a object with keys and values that passed on filter and functions validates, and i am learning ramda, and for know i dont know how to use ramda functions to refacts this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why?

I think you need to consider *why* you want to convert this to Ramda 
(Disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author) Ramda is a library, a toolkit.  Use it when it helps clean up your code or when it makes it easier to understand the problem and its solution.  Don't use it when it doesn't.

That said, I did refactor it, using Ramda:

### A Refactoring

I simply tried to refactor it a bit.  In the end, I replaced all your helper functions with a single one that takes a list of conditions such as `['limit', 10, numberRequired]` to create a function equivalent to your `selector`.

I did use a few Ramda functions along the way, but the only one that offers substantive help is [`assoc`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#assoc), which creates a new object from an old one and a key and value.  Using, for instance, `compose(Boolean, length)` is cleaner than `const stringRequired = string => !!string.length`, but it's not a large difference.

The important change, to my mind, is the `makeSelector` function, which makes creating your `selector` function much more declarative.  It's a bit ugly, and I probably would write it differently if I were starting from scratch, but I did this in a series of steps, inlining your helper functions until I had a reasonably short function that had the same behavior.

```js
// rules
const stringRequired = R.compose(Boolean, R.length)
const numberRequired = number => Number.isInteger(number)


// utils
const makeSelector = (conditions) => (query = {}) => R.reduce(
  (select, [key, initial, validate]) => {
    const value = key in select && validate(select[key]) ? select[key] : initial;
    return validate(value) ? R.assoc(key, value, select) : select
  },
  query,
  conditions
)

// main
const selector = makeSelector([
  ['limit', 10, numberRequired],
  ['name', '', stringRequired]
])

console.log(selector());
console.log(selector({ name: 'David Costa' }));
console.log(selector({ limit: 50 }));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: The `stringRequired` from Scott Christopher's answer is an improvement over mine.  Mine keeps your initial behavior.  His does a better validation.

Comment: And I also missed the fact that `Number.isInteger` should be inlined.

Comment: I get suggestions to learn ramda, because ramda can solve my problems, because i am always creating the same functions to do the something, and ramda can help with it and ramda it is nice for use composable functions and functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little hesitant to simply respond with a translated block of code and my recommendation for learning going forward would be to try replace the functions you already have one by one with those from Ramda.

Hesitation aside, the following offers one example of what your code might look like when using various functions from Ramda.

```js
// The existing check for `!!string.length` allows for potential issues with
// arrays being passed in and incorrectly validating, so this will ensure the
// value is indeed a string before checking its length

const stringRequired = R.both(R.is(String), R.complement(R.isEmpty))

// `addFilter` produces a function that takes an object and uses the provided
// function to validate the value associated with the provided key if it exists
// otherwise using the provided `initial` value. If valid, an object containing
// the key and value will be returned, otherwise an empty object is returned.

const addFilter = (validate, initial, key) =>
  R.pipe(
    R.propOr(initial, key),
    R.ifElse(validate, R.objOf(key), R.always({}))
  )

// `selector` takes an object and passes it to each function generated by
// calling `addFilter`, merging the resulting objects together.

const selector = (q = {}) =>
  R.converge(R.merge, [
    addFilter(stringRequired, '', 'name'),
    addFilter(Number.isInteger, 10, 'limit')
  ])(q)

console.log(selector())
console.log(selector({ name: 'David Costa' }))
console.log(selector({ limit: 50 }))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's interesting to see how different people refactor the same code!

Comment: Exactly, first i create the code withou ramda, and i am trying to replace each function.

Comment: That approach can cause problems, though, as it misses the possibilities of significantly better design.  It's fine as a learning exercise, but be wary of it when trying to write production code.